# How to apply UIEdgeInsets to CGImage?

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage

How does one apply `UIEdgeInsets` (or some variation thereof) to a `CGImage`? This is what I'm ultimately trying to achieve but the `CGImage` is not recognizing the bottom inset applied to the `UIImage` before it is converted to a `CGImage`.

```
var image = someUIImage
image = image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: (image.size.height / 2), right: 0))
let imageCG: CGImage = image.cgImage!
layer.contents = imageCG
```

And I can't apply an inset to the `CGImage` directly (as seen here).

```
let image = someUIImage.cgImage!
image. // can't apply any inset here
layer.contents = image
```

Workaround?

Comment: Can you get things to display properly in a `UIView` or some subclass of it?

Comment: I can but unfortunately the `CGImage` is what this particular delegate method requires (the image is being used as an annotation on a map) so I have very little wiggle room.

Comment: I'm actually working through some code this afternoon. I've have code to turn any `UIView` and it's subviews into a `UIImage` that works great. Now I need to resize/crop/scale that image (actually it's a mask) to reflect a particular size. IMHO, once you have a `UIImge`, changing it to a `CGImage` (or the reverse, which is what I'm working through right now) is one line of code. Do you think this would work for you? (1) Get everything, insets included, set in a view. (2) Create a scaled image of that view of the proper size. If so, when I'm done (hopefully today) I'll post the full code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot “apply `UIEdgeInsets`” to a `CGImage` because a `CGImage` doesn't have an `alignmentRectInsets` property. A `UIImage` stores several properties that a `CGImage` does not, including `alignmentRectInsets`.

Note that the `alignmentRectInsets` property exists to influence how auto layout poses a `UIImageView` containing the image. A `UIImageView` sets its own `alignmentRectInsets` from the `alignmentRectInsets` of its `UIImage`. Auto layout then uses the alignment rect when computing the frame of the `UIImageView`.

Auto layout doesn't work with layers, so a `CALayer` has no need for a `alignmentRectInsets` property.

In other words, what you're asking for doesn't really make sense.

If you revise your question to explain what visual effect you want, I might be able to offer advice on how to get it.

Comment: Very well explained :) I did not know that UIImageView takes alignmentRectInsets from UIImage !!! hence +1.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, I found it very helpful. The visual effect I want is simply to apply a bottom margin to the `CGImage`. I would use a standard `UIImage` if I were able but this image will be an annotation on a map which must be of type `CGImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

let resizable = img.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8), resizingMode: .stretch)

Comment: Unfortunately, the inset still doesn't carry over to the `CGImage`.